# How to display in UWP ListView the sum of every single entry?

Tags: .net, listview, uwp, binding

The following scenario
(I have greatly simplified it for this example):

I have a list of groups.
Each group is assigned elements with amounts.

This is the list from my ViewModel:

```
public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

And these are my Models:

```
public class Group 
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Element MainElement { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public int ElementId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

This is how the ListView looks like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding GroupId}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SumOfAllItemsInThisGroup}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The whole UWP app works just fine, but I'd like to show in the list the sum of all elements in this group.

I do not want to save the value in the database.
Or do I have to?

I have tried something like:

```
var myGroups = new SuperGroup
{
    Group = group,
    Amount = db.Elements.Where(e => e.Group == group).Select(e => e.Amount).Sum()
};

public class SuperGroup 
{
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public double SumAmount { get; set; }
}
```

And changed the Bindings to `Text="{Binding Group.*}"`
but unfortunately no more values were displayed

Is there a way to work with converters?

Or do you have a very simple solution for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @nico-zhu-msft, he has brought me to the following solution!

I added an not mapped property to my group and was able to do without an list of elements because of direct database access.

```
[NotMapped]
public double SumAmount {
    get
    {
        using (var db = new DBContext())
        {
            return db.Elements.Where(e => e.GroupId == myGroupId).Select(e => e.Amount).Sum();
        }
    }
}
```

and just used it as he wrote

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SumAmount}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> but I'd like to show in the list the sum of all elements in this group.

Your model structure is strange, The `Element` field  of `Group` is Element but not `List<Element>`. But there is `Amount` field in `Element` class. If you just want to show this field, you could use following.

`<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Element.Amount}" />`

If your model class like the following, you could add SumAmount field that used to record all the element's amount.

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Element> Elements { get; set; }
    public double SumAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return Elements.Select(e=>e.Amount).Sum();
        }               
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SumAmount}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Sorry it was late yesterday, I edited my post. So the Element in the Group ist just the MainElement and only the elements know the group ID, the group itself has no list of elements. But I like your idea, I simply do an database select on the elements in this group in the getter for the sum

Comment: @MichaelM. Good Job, If the answer is helpful, please consider accept it.